# UIView animation with a bow, not in a straight line

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to have my animation with a bow and not in a straight line.
This is my code:

```
UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-125, 100, 125, 125)];
    logoImageView.image = logoImage;
    logoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview:logoImageView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width - 192, 190, logoImageView.frame.size.width, logoImageView.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have also tried this, but it doesn't work (it only takes the last center to move from).

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
logoImageView.center = CGPointMake ...
logoImageView.center = CGPointMake ...
logoImageView.center = CGPointMake ...
```

> etc.

```
logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width - 192, 190, logoImageView.frame.size.width, logoImageView.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Short answer: you need Core Animation and CAKeyframeAnimation to do a path. I'm on a phone so I can't give you code more for about an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment you will need `CAKeyframeAnimation` to do multiple values like that. The easy way is to just specify the values and specify a `calculationMode` for how they should be interpolated. If that doesn't give you the result you want you could specify any `CGPath` you want the view to be animated along. Code for what you are trying to do would look something like this.

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *curvedAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
curvedAnimation.duration = 3.0;
curvedAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationCubic;
curvedAnimation.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:currentPoint],
                           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:firstPoint],
                           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:secondPoint],
                           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPoint]];

curvedAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards; // Show first value before animation begins

logoImageView.layer.position = endPoint; // Change position to end value (Core Animation only performs the animation, it won't change the property you are animating)
[logoImageView.layer addAnimation:curvedAnimation
                           forKey:@"my bow animation"];
```

---

If you are new to Core Animation. It is found in `QuartzCore.framework` which you have to add to your project as well as `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So `curvedAnimation.values` is optional? I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: "optional"? Those are the actual values it will pass through. The position will animate from `currentPoint` to `firstPoint` to `secondPoint` and end up at `endPoint`. Without the values array the animation doesn't know how to animate.

Comment: Ok, I thought, that `curvedAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationCubic;` was enough (if you don't want specific positions. But I will try it tonight. Thank you for your answer.